# Booth's algorithm Verilog synthesizable

Tags: algorithm, verilog, fpga, synthesis

I am trying to implement Booth's algorithm (a finite state machine implementation) for a Xilinx FPGA.
Basically, at the start signal I will initialize my auxiliary regs, then I will go in state 0, where I will start to compare the 2 bits and do the shifting. I will repeat this until state 4 is reached.

```
assign Result = P[8:1];

always@(posedge clk or negedge start)
    if(start == 1)
    begin
            // initialize with start values
        state <= 3'd0;
    end

    else
    if(state == 3'd0 || state == 3'd1 || state == 3'd2 || state == 3'd3)
    begin
       // compare bits and shift data
    end
endmodule
```

Test module

```
clk = 0;
a = 4'b0011;
b = 4'b0011;
b = ~b+1;
start = 1;
#10;
start = 0;
```

clk becomes ~clk after #5 time units.

I do not own an FPGA, so I cannot test the program (I'll have to test it later at class).

I am testing it with Icarus. The problem is that the auxiliary regs are not initialized before the first posedge of the clock.

What can I do in order to properly initialize my auxiliary variables and to maintain the code to be synthesizable? I've tried using a for loop and an initial begin, and the simulation works fine, but it will not work on the FPGA (because I have to use #delays).

Comment: The easiest way would be to add `reset` signal and initialize regs when `reset == 1` (or `0` for `rst_n`).

Comment: What are the "auxiliary regs" which are not initialized? `state`?

Comment: Solved it! The "auxiliary regs" that were not initialized were the ones were I hold the intermediate results, (the ones were I concat 0000 with 'a' for example) or 2's complement for number a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ASIC it is best to use active low resets to set initial values however for FPGAs it is common just to set initial values in an `initial` blocks.

```
initial begin
  state = 'd0 ;
end

always@(posedge clk) begin
  if(state == 3'd0 || state == 3'd1 || state == 3'd2 || state == 3'd3)begin
    // compare bits and shift data
    state <= 3'd4 ;
  end
endmodule
```

Using active low resets.

```
always@(posedge clk or negedge rst_n) begin
  if (~rst_n) begin
    state <= 'd0 ;
  end 
  else begin
    if(state == 3'd0 || state == 3'd1 || state == 3'd2 || state == 3'd3)begin
      // compare bits and shift data
      state <= 3'd4 ;
    end
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: Here is the reason why active resets are used in ASIC https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.verilog/WI1Ob8C0dzg